# Fundamental theorem of calculus, differentiable at the endpoints.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

One version states:

> Let f be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed
>   interval $[a,b]$. Let f be the function defined for all x in $[a,b]$,
>   by $F(x)=\int_{a}^xf(t)dt$. Then, F is continuous on [a,b],
>   differentiable in the open interval (a,b), and $F'(x)=f(x)$. For all x
>   in $(a,b)$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part

My question is, can it be proved that the right hand derivative of F at a exists? Or are there examples where the right hand derivative of F at a, does not exist?

Comment: Yes, though we don't deal with the possibility in first-semester calculus:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thank you, but sorry if my question was unclear. I know what left and right hand derivatives are, but in your link I can not see that they mention the fundamental theorem. My question is if we can change differentiability to [a,b], not only (a,b) as is stated in the theorem. But when we look at a or b, we only look at right and left derivatives. If the theorem can not be stated this way, is there a counterexample?

Comment: "if we can change differentiability to [a,b], not only (a,b) as is stated in the theorem" --> Differentiability is only defined for open intervals.  This is to prevent ambiguous situations like yours from occurring.  The FTC theorem cannot be stated that way simply by the definitions of "differentiable" and "derivative".  If you want an FTC theorem that works the way you suggest, you will have to construct a new notion of differentiability that is compatible with your ideas.

Comment: @nukeguy That is basically what I am wondering. If it is possible to prove that F has a right derivative at a, or if it is not possible to prove it, what is the counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually an immediate consequence of the Mean Value Theorem (so a very similar argument to the one just given by @J.E.).

**LEMMA**: Suppose $F$ is continuous at $a$ and $F'$ exists for all $x\in (a,a+\delta)$. Suppose, moreoever, that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} F'(x)$ exists. Then the right-hand derivative $F'_+(a)$ is equal to that limit.

We apply this by noting that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in (a,a+\delta)$ and continuity of $f$ at $a$ (from the right) gives us the existence of the limit.

**Proof of Lemma**: For $0<h<\delta$, consider
$\dfrac{F(a+h)-F(a)}h$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there is $c_h\in (a,a+h)$ with
$$\frac{F(a+h)-F(a)}h = F'(c_h).$$
If we suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} F'(x)$ exists, then we infer immediately that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} F'(c_h)$ exists, as $c_h\to a^+$ as $h\to 0^+$. (You can write down a careful $\delta$-$\epsilon$ argument here if you desire.) Therefore, the right-hand derivative $F'_+(a)$ exists and equals this limit.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can consider [left/right derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability), or even [Dini derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative) of functions.

Generally, when we are looking at a real-valued function $G$ that is only defined on an interval $[a,b]$, we think of the derivatives at $a$ and $b$ as simply being the right-hand and left-hand derivatives at those points (respectively). That is, when we look at the derivative $G'(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{G(x)-G(a)}{x-a}$, the limit should be taken using only values of $x$ that lie inside $[a,b]$, since that is the domain we are working in. This is equivalent to taking the limit only from the right of $a$.

To show that the right derivative of $F$ at $a$ is $f(a)$, we can just use the same argument from one of the [standard proofs of the FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_first_part).

For $x \in [a,b]$, we have that $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$.

Then $$F(x) - F(a) = \int_a^x f(t) dt - \int_a^a f(t) dt = \int_a^x f(t)dt,$$

as $\int_a^a f(t)dt = 0$.

By the [Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals), for each $x \in (a, b)$, there exists $c_x \in [a, x]$ such that $$\int_a^x f(t)dt = f(c_x)(x-a).$$ Rearranging, we obtain that
$$\frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a} = f(c_x),$$
so that the right derivative of $F$ at $a$ is
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(c_x)$$
Since each $c_x$ lies in the interval $[a, x], c_x$ must converge to $a$ as $x$ approaches $a$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, we have that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(c_x) = f(a)$, so that the right derivative of $F$ at $a$ is $f(a)$, as desired.

The argument for the left derivative of $F$ at $b$ is analogous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this definition of the right derivative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_and_right_derivative#Derivatives_arising_from_one-sided_limits

I believe that this proof will show $F'(a) = f(a)$.  That is, we want to show

$$ \lim_{x \to a+} \frac{ F(x) - F(a) }{ x - a } - f'(a) = 0 \tag{1} $$

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Since $F$ is continuous, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that

$$F(y) - F(a) = \frac{\epsilon(b-a)}{3} \tag{2}$$

for all $y$ satisfying $a < y < a + \delta_1$.

Since $F$ is differentiable at $y > a$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that

$$\frac{F(z) - F(y)}{z - y} - f'(y) < \frac{\epsilon}{3} \tag{3}$$

for all $y < z < y + \delta_2$.

Since $f'$ is continuous at $a$, there exists $\delta_3 > 0$ such that

$$f'(w) - f'(a) < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

for all $w$ satisfying $a < w < a + \delta_3$.

Then, choose $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \min \left\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 , \delta_3 \right\}$.  Let $u$ take on any value between $a < u < a + \delta$.  Then, we can pick $z$ to be some value between $a$ and $u$.  From there,

\begin{align*}
 \frac{F(u) - F(a)}{u - a} - f'(a) &= \frac{F(u) - F(z) + F(z) - F(a)}{ u - a} - f'(z) + f'(z) - f'(a) \\
     &= \frac{F(u) - F(z)}{u-a} + \frac{F(z) - F(a)}{u-a} - f'(z) + f'(z) - f'(a) \\
     &< \frac{F(u) - F(z)}{u-z} + \frac{F(z) - F(a)}{z-a} - f'(z) + f'(z) - f'(a) \\
     &= \left[\frac{F(z) - F(a)}{z-a}\right] +\left[\frac{F(u) - F(z)}{u-z}  - f'(z)\right] + \left[f'(z) - f'(a)\right]  \\
     &< \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} \\
     &= \epsilon
\end{align*}
This proves the limit of interest and shows that $F$ is right differentiable at $a$.

Comment: Are you using equation (2) to get $\left| \frac{F(z)-F(a)}{z-a}\right| \leq \epsilon/3$ in the second to last line? I am not sure this follows from equation (2); one has that $\left| \frac{F(z)-F(a)}{z-a} \right| \leq \epsilon(b-a)/(3(z-a))$, but since $(b-a) \geq (z-a)$, this may not be less than or equal to $\epsilon/3$.