# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: definition of differentiable interval?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question on the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) definition:

$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt
$$

where $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ then:

$$
(F'(x) = f(x)) \land (x \in (a,b))
$$

**Questions** $F'(x) = f(x)$ is defined on $(a, b)$ and earlier $f(x)$ is defined on $[a,b]$.  Does this make the antiderivative a partial function?  Also how can $F'(x) = f(x)$ if the domain is different then the earlier definition?

Comment: The general idea is that derivative definition assumes difference quotients in both directions around the point of interest.  At the end points you don't have that.

Comment: I believe this coudl help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126069/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-differentiable-at-the-endpoints?rq=1

Comment: It’s a different question but has the same theorem involved.

Comment: @herb that seems intuitive but I haven’t found details on it on Wiki or other searches. It also raises the same questions in the OP. For instance, does the derivative of the Antiderivative result in the original function with open  instead of closed interval for the domain

Answer (score 1):

$F(x)$ is not a partial function, since it is defined everywhere on $[a,b]: F(a) = \int_a^a f(t)dt = 0,$ and $F(b) = \int_a^b f(t)dt$.

Generally, when we are looking at a real-valued function $G$ that is only defined on an interval $[a,b]$, we think of the derivatives at $a$ and $b$ as simply being the [right and left derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability) at those points (respectively). That is, when we look at the derivative $G'(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{G(x)-G(a)}{x-a}$, the limit should be taken using only values of $x$ that lie inside $[a,b]$, since that is the domain we are working in. This is equivalent to taking the limit only from the right of $a$.

In the case of the FTC, these one-sided limits $F'(b) = \lim_{x \rightarrow b^-} \frac{F(x)-F(b)}{x-b}$ and $F'(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \frac{F(x)-F(a)}{x-a}$
do exist, and are equal to $f(b)$ and $f(a)$ respectively, as explained in my answer to this [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4221511/957456).

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt\approx \frac{f(x)\times(x+h-x)}{h}\to f(x)$ as $h\to 0$  Approximation from definition of Riemann integral.

End points excluded since for $x=a$ and $h\lt 0$ or $x=b$ and $h\gt 0$, the integral cannot be defined.

$f(x)$ must be continuous at $x$ for $F(x)$ to be differentiable at $x$.

Comment: If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, F : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F(x) = \int_a^b {f(x)} dx$, then $F' : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  It appears $F'$ is a partial inverse of $F$.  Is that correct?